# Heatmap dendrogram using "ComplexHeatmap" package

Tags: cluster-analysis, heatmap, dendrogram

I'm using the "ComplexHeatmap" package to create a heatmap of the correlations in a matrix.
I want to use my own clustering for the dendrogram of the heatmap so I run the code below:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap);
mat = matrix(rnorm(800),80,10);
cor.mat= cor(mat)
dist.mat = (1-cor.mat)/2;
rowdist = dist(as.matrix(dist.mat), method = "euclidean")
rowcluster = hclust(rowdist, method = "ward.D2")
coldist = dist(t(as.matrix(dist.mat)), method = "euclidean")
colcluster = hclust(coldist, method = "ward.D2")
par(mfrow=c(1,2));plot(rowcluster);plot(colcluster);
Heatmap(cor.mat ,cluster_rows=rowcluster, cluster_columns=colcluster)
```

Problem is, I get different clustering on the rows and columns (asymmetrical), despite the fact that the cluster objects are the same.
Even if I pass the Heatmap function the exact same object for rows and columns it still displays a different order for rows and columns.
if I just create the dendrograms i.e. plot(rowcluster) or plot(colcluster) they are identical.

I want to get a symmetrical heatmap.
Any idea why this happens?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use rowclust=colclust.

No need to transpose.

But note that you have a distance matrix already, so "euclidean" is wrong. You are computing a distance matrix of your distance matrix!